# How to implement Cloudinary in node.js/React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

I was struggling for several months to implement Cloudinary into a MERN web app, so I am running out of options to find the answer.
Basically, the problem here is that I don't have the knowledge to write successfully the necessary code to make it work.

Here is some insight:
I need to upload photos to Cloudinary for a Blog web page, (the problem is in the first two code files)
I was able to make it work for user's profilePics in the last two code files ( Settings.jsx & Settings.js ).. now I had to do almost the same,but that works for images in posts (Write.jsx & Posts.js ).
Feel free to ask for more info about

Front-End Write.jsx

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import "./write.css";

import { Context } from "../../context/Context";
import { axiosInstance } from "../../config";
import { FcAddImage } from "react-icons/fc";

export default function Write() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [desc, setDesc] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);

  const { user, dispatch } = useContext(Context);

  const photo = user.photo;

  console.log("post info", title, desc, file, user);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (file) {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("id", user._id);
      data.append("type", "file");
      data.append("avatar", file);
      try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.post("/upload", "/posts", data);
        setSuccess(true);
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_FAILURE" });
      }
    }
  };
  /*try {
        await axiosInstance.post("/upload", data);
      } catch (err) {}
    }
    try {
      const res = await axiosInstance.post("/posts", newPost);
      window.location.replace("/post/" + res.data._id);
    } catch (err) {}*/

  return (
    <div className="write">
      {file && (
        <img
          className="writeImg"
          src={file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : photo}
          alt=""
        />
      )}
      <form className="writeForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="writeFormGroup">
          <label htmlFor="fileInput">
            Image
            <FcAddImage className="icon" />
          </label>
          <input
            action="/:id"
            method="POST"
            type="file"
            id="fileInput"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Title"
            className="writeInput"
            autoFocus={true}
            onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="writeFormGroup">
          <textarea
            placeholder="Tell your story..."
            type="text"
            className="writeInput writeText"
            onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button className="writeSubmit" type="submit">
          Publish
        </button>
        {success && (
          <span
            style={{ color: "green", textAlign: "center", marginTop: "20px" }}
          >
            Post has been uploaded...
          </span>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Server-side Post.js

```
const User = require("../models/User");
const Post = require("../models/Post");
const cloudinary = require("../utils/cloudinary");
const upload = require("../utils/multer");

//UPLOAD FILE
router.post("/upload", upload.single("avatar"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Upload image to cloudinary
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    //save changes
    post.photo = result.secure_url;
    res.status(200).json(savedPost);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//CREATE POST
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const newPost = new Post(req.body);
  try {
    const savedPost = await newPost.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedPost);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//UPDATE POST
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (post.username === req.body.username) {
      try {
        const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
          req.params.id,
          {
            $set: req.body,
          },
          { new: true }
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedPost);
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("You can update only your post!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//DELETE POST
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    if (post.username === req.body.username) {
      try {
        await post.delete();
        res.status(200).json("Post has been deleted...");
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).json("You can delete only your post!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//GET POST
router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    res.status(200).json(post);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//GET ALL POSTS
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const username = req.query.user;
  const catName = req.query.cat;
  try {
    let posts;
    if (username) {
      posts = await Post.find({ username });
    } else if (catName) {
      posts = await Post.find({
        categories: {
          $in: [catName],
        },
      });
    } else {
      posts = await Post.find();
    }
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Server-side Settings.js

```
//POST IMAGES
router.post("/upload", upload.single("avatar"), async (req, res) => {
  console.log('/users/upload triggered')
  try {
    // Upload image to cloudinary
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
    // Save user
    User.findById(req.body.id, (err, user) => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      user.profilePic = result.secure_url
      user.save((err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        res.json(user);
        console.log('user saved')
      })
    });
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: Pardon! I am unable to understand, Can you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reaching out! I need to upload photos to Cloudinary, this are the errors in the console xhr.js:177          POST http://localhost:5000/api/upload 404 (Not Found)
xhr.js:177          POST http://localhost:5000/api/posts/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I need to upload photos to Cloudinary for a Blog web page, (first two code files ) although I was able to make it work for user's profile pics in the last two code files ( Settings.jsx & Settings.js ).. now I had to do almost the same, that works for images in posts (Write.jsx & Posts.js ). Feel free to ask for more info about

Comment: At this point, I believe you need to determine where you are getting the error It can be either the server of the client. If you are seeing 500 internal server errors I'm inclined to say its the server. I believe you are consoling out the error in server side what did it say?

Also, Did you try using postman first to check if the route is correctly working?

Answer (score 0):

**I made conection to cloudinary changing  the line**

```js
const res = await axiosInstance.post("/posts/upload", data);
```

but now, I can't post the 'posts', but is a step in the right direction

```js
      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        if (file) {
          const data = new FormData();
          data.append("id", user._id);
          data.append("type", "file");
          data.append("avatar", file);
          try {
            const res = await axiosInstance.post("/posts/upload", data);
            setSuccess(true);
            dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_SUCCESS", payload: res.data });
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_FAILURE" });
          }
        }
      };
```